# How can I create a level and perfect east-west line?

Tags: geometry

Imagine you have a 10'x30' solar array.

(A) = 30'

Side A needs to be positioned perpendicular or facing True South, which is 14 degrees west of magnetic south. (Look at S on compass... 180 degrees. True S is 194 degrees.

How can I create an East-West line that will make side A perfectly perp. to the 194 degree True South?

I plan on using two wooden stakes with a string attached to it, while lining up the line with the compass needle at 194 degrees... Hope that helps with your thought process :)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you have a horizontal surface and a clear day available, set up a sundial in the morning and mark the position of the shadow somewhen in the morning. In the afternoon, wait until the shadow has the exact same *length* as the one marked in the morning, and then mark the point the shadow ends. The line between the two marked points will be perfectly east-west.

(This can be done most precisely at midsummer, where the polar distance of the sun doesn't vary during the day).

---

Or, of course, if you want to use your magnetic compass and trust your value for its deviation, just subtract 90° from 194° and sight along a magnetic heading of 104°, which should then be true east.

Comment: I'm was planning on attaching two 2x4's together so that it was a T, a half crosshair if you will. Using the single piece with represents 194 degrees, which would then line up the perpendicular piece with 104 and 284 degrees. I would then run a string parallel to the longer piece of would, making a string that is perfectly perpendicular the true south (194 degrees). What are your thoughts on this? I'm very confident that the two ends would obviously represent the east-west line in respect to true directions.

Comment: @Brandon: Is what you're really asking how to construct a straight line on the ground that's perpendicular to one you have already chosen?

Comment: That's right. My father doesn't believe it's that simple.